# Codeigniter PHP - Parse SOAP (WDSL) result

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, soap

I am currently retrieving information from a Web Service using:

```
$serviceData= new SoapClient('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xx/WebService/WebService.svc?wsdl');
$response = $serviceData->GetMyInformation();
var_dump($response);
```

The result from var_dump is below:

```
object(stdClass)#15 (1) 
{ ["GetDatabaseResult"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (1)
    { ["DatabaseInformation"]=> array(4) 

        {   [0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-07-06T09:36:03" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" } 

            [1]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:49:02" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" } 

            [2]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:52:38" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" } 

            [3]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:53:38" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" }

        }
    }
}
```

What I need is a foreach loop that I can retrieve each key and value:

```
DateCreated: 2016-07-06T09:36:03
CurrencyCode: USD
```

I tried using `json_encode($response)` which removed the `object(stdClass)#15 (1)` and the `json_dencode($response)` which got it to this point:

```
array(1) 
{ ["GetDatabaseResult"]=> array(1) 
    { ["DatabaseInformation"]=> array(4) 
        {   [0]=> array(2) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-07-06T09:36:03" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" }

            [1]=> array(17) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:49:02" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" } 

            [2]=> array(17) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:52:38" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" }

            [3]=> array(17) 
            { ["DateCreated"]=> string(19) "2016-12-07T02:52:38" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "USD" }

        }
    }
}
```

I know it's a nested array, but how would I parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the encode/decode loop. Try this:

```
foreach($response->GetDatabaseResult->DatabaseInformation as $entry){
  error_log("Date Created: ".$entry->DateCreated."; Currency Code: ".$entry->CurrencyCode);
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Can you explain your thought process on breaking up the JSON and how you were able to arrive at: $response->GetDatabaseResult->DatabaseInformation. I've always had this problem of not knowing when to apply -> (objects) because mainly the JSON i posted above looked like associative arrays.

Comment: It does take a little bit of thought to go from the var_dump output, but anywhere you see `object(stdClass)` then that's an `->`, and anywhere you see `array` that's either a `[]` lookup or a  `foreach`. You might need to experiment with using the proper key for the array lookup, but that should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks much for the advice. Just upvoted your answer.

Comment: Not sure if you can help but i am making a call to the service again but this time when there is no data this is returned: object(stdClass)#15 (1) 
{ ["GetDatabaseResult"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (0) { }}     what is different from the first result is that the Key: DatabaseInformation is left out so when it goes to the foreach loop it cannot find it. $response->GetDatabaseResult->DatabaseInformation. How can i detect that it does not exist?

Comment: You can use `isset($response->GetDatabaseResult->DatabaseInformation)` to check for availability.